# Funny integral meme from Facebook

Tags: calculus, integration

The following is a meme from Facebook. It's supposed to be a joke, but is there any serious mathematical way to evaluate this?

(Tbh I just want to impress my friends by giving a smartass answer)

[image]

Comment: Two pies and a half ([spoiler](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(10+sin(x))%2F(2+x)+from+0+to+infinity)).

Comment: beer bottle = 10, burger = 5, beer glass = 2, dog = x, $\int_0^{\infty} \frac {10 sin x}{2x} dx = \frac {5\pi}{2}$ = (burger)(pie) / beer bottle? 2.5 pi?

Comment: @DougM Ah, totally forgot about the Dirichlet integral. You can post that as an answer; I will accept it.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Could you (re)include an image, please?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Google image search found the image at https://goo.gl/images/qgT2ex

Comment: @MarkS. Thank you!